# i want to validate a date for my attandance request model which accociates with user model ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Model `AttendanceRequest` that has a uniqueness validation built in.

here is my model:

```
class AttendanceRequest < ApplicationRecord

  validates_uniqueness_of :login_time, :logout_time

end
```

Currently the model validates for uniqueness over all users, but I would like it to validate uniqueness for individual users, not every user.

Can you help?

Comment: I would argue that every user will be the current_user at some point in time. Why do you only want users to be valid when they are logged in?

Comment: sorry for that naming conversion but my approach is to enter the new entry which is not exist if exist then show an error thanks for response @spickermann

Comment: can you not just do a "null: false" on the database record to make sure it exists? how important is it that you know it has a unique record to the second on those times?

Comment: no i just want to enter a new date entry which is not present if present then show error ....thanks for response @jad

Comment: have you looked at `#scope` in `validations_uniqueness_of` : `validates_uniqueness_of :login_time, scope: :user` for instance

Comment: thanks its help me to go ahead few steps @Jad

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you need to do something different link give default value of logout time for first time

Comment: sorry for that naming conversion but my approach is to enter the new entry which is not exist if exist then show an error

Comment: still unable to understand your issue

Comment: just suppose you enter a new record with date which is exist but it save because of no validation so i want to validate for not repeat a date of existing record

Comment: in example.rb  use befor_save callback and validate the same